# Sump pump water now high. Where’s it coming from?

Tags: water, pump, level

We moved into a new house in June. I didn’t pay a lot of attention to the sump pump to start but the water only sat about 2-3” full in the sump pit.
 It’s now always at the level of the first inlet pipe about 9”. 
As a result of the new water level I have replaced the sump pump and back up after finding them in not great condition and thinking this was the issue. This didn’t lower the water and so I raised the float because the new water level would cause it to be going off every minute or five if I left it at the old height. (This did not happen before, as the water level was lower) 
It empties Okay now I replaced the pump so it’s not a pump issue  but always fills to this new higher water level. Again I raised the float as the new high water level would have it running constantly when it didn’t need to before. 
I have no idea why the water is higher than before. It’s not rained more than normal and it’s now been several months at this new level. 
Any ideas? I’m concerned that the water is slightly over the inlet valve for one thing and that this new high level might mean something serious is going on. Th water seems to come in from the bottom.

Comment: You admit you raised the float, what’s the question?

Comment: A photo of the low-water-level scenario might be enlightening.

Comment: I had to raise the pump because the water which was sitting at about 2-3” normally is now sitting at about 9” as it’s normal level. I raised the pump to stop it running every five minutes as I don’t want it to burn out before an actual rain!! The question is what could be causing the water level to have a new ‘ normal’ much higher level than before when there has been no extra rain and it’s been a few months now with no change.

Comment: Sounds like the water may not be actually leaving or you have a new source of water (like a leaking pipe). It is possible that the hose is leaking someplace relatively near the pump and the water is essentially running back into the hole (depending on the details this could be several feet away).

Comment: I changed the hose and extended it... only to later discover it actually flows into the sewer anyhow. Must have been converted in last few years as did have an outside pipe.  The return valve is new and there are two so won’t be leaking back in (I’ve checked it was the right way). Could it be a pipe in the walls then?

Comment: So is the question “where is the water coming from?”

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn’t clear before

Comment: It could just be natural seasonal variation in ground water saturation. This is the first year in your home and you moved in during the summer when rains are not generally as prevalent as spring/fall in a lot of climates and a lot of the ground water may have dried up at that point only to return during the rainy season.

Comment: Janet, when you installed the new sump pump, did you include a check valve? If you didn't keep your old one, or if your old pump had one built in and your new pump doesn't, it sounds to me like the pump is just cycling itself over and over trying to pump out the same water, then allowing it to back flow, which is what the check valve is necessary to prevent.

Comment: Yes thank you, the new pump has its own check valve but also I added a new one and it is facing the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the same situation as a friend of mine in northern IL. His basement contacted a shallow aquifer. He had 4 sump pumps in his pit; one ran all the time, the second ran if it had rained recently, the third ran if it was raining, the fourth was for emergency's.  Basically nothing he could do except have spare pumps or move.

Comment: Thank you. Aquifer or possibly seasonal change seems likely. I’ll see how we are in spring although feel that will be worse not better. Thanks